# SQL Server 2012 create list of VARBINARY in single XML element

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I am currently struggling to find a solution to the following problem.

I have a result set of VARBINARY values - for example:

- QAAAAAAAAAE=
- QAAAAAAAAAQ=

these results Need to be packed into a XML Element delimited by a single space (to siginify an array of values). Example of how the result should look:

```
<results>QAAAAAAAAAE= QAAAAAAAAAQ=</results>
```

The issue I am having while using XML PATH is that I cannot combine a ' ' (varchar) and the result varbinary field. If I add the ' ' before the result and then convert to varbinary the result is incorrect due to having converted the  space as well. Here is an example of what I have attempted thus far:

```
(
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ' ' + CONVERT( VARBINARY, id)
    FROM results
    FOR XML PATH('ns2:children')
    ),1,1,'')
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls. try short of `SQL` Command which could help u to achieve the above result :

```
SELECT REPLACE(T.Data, '</results><results>', ' ')
FROM
(
    SELECT STUFF(
                (
                    SELECT DATA [results]
                    FROM <table_name> FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '<') [Data]
) T;
```

**Result :**

```
<results>QAAAAAAAAAE= QAAAAAAAAAQ=</results>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not deal with XML on string level. This might have various side effects...

You can try this:

I fill a table with some values in a `VARBINARY` column:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(SomeData VARBINARY(MAX));
INSERT INTO @table VALUES(0x12AF)
                        ,(CAST('test' AS VARBINARY(MAX)))
                        ,(CAST(GETDATE() AS VARBINARY(MAX)));
SELECT * 
FROM @table;
```

The result

```
SomeData
0x12AF
0x74657374
0x0000A81100AD9F69
```

If you get this as XML, the conversion to base64 is done implicitly

```
SELECT * FROM @table FOR XML PATH('result')
```

the result

```
<result>
  <SomeData>Eq8=</SomeData>
</result>
<result>
  <SomeData>dGVzdA==</SomeData>
</result>
<result>
  <SomeData>AACoEQCtn2k=</SomeData>
</result>
```

Now there is `XQuery-function data()` to your rescue. It will automatically concatenate all sub-values separated by a blank:

```
SELECT(
       SELECT * 
       FROM @table 
       FOR XML PATH('result'),TYPE
       ).query('data(/result/SomeData)') AS result 
FOR XML PATH('results')
```

The result is

```
<results>
  <result>Eq8= dGVzdA== AACoEQCtn2k=</result>
</results>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what do you want?! A way to get `<results>QAAAAAAAAAE= QAAAAAAAAAQ=</results>` as result is:

```
select ltrim((
    select ' '+cast(id as varchar(50))
    from t
    group by id
    for xml path(''))) results
for xml path('');
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/8992)